# JFrame doesn't get closed completely

Tags: java, swing, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I am using VLCJ binding to create a video player.

My code:

```
public class MyVideoPlayer {

    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;
    static String VLCLIBPATH = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC";

    public MyVideoPlayer(String source) {
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), VLCLIBPATH);
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("VLC Player");
        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
        frame.setSize(1366, 768);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(source);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    } 
}
```

I call this video player from another frame by `new VideoPlayer(source)`.
When I use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, the frame gets closed but the sound still won't go..

How can I close the video player frame completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Declare the close operation as `JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`.
2. Add a `WindowListener` as follows (adapt to your code as needed):

   ```
   frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
           mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().stop(); // Very important!
           frame.dispose();
       }
   });
   ```

It will likely be necessary to declare `frame` & `mediaPlayerComponent` as `final` in order to access them from within an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

**Use JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE**

i.e `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

> The exit application default window close operation. If a window has this set as the close operation and is closed in an applet, a SecurityException may be thrown. It is recommended you only use this in an application.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE

If you don't want to use Exit on close which will close your application then

**Add a Listener on windowClosing, when the listener call the method stop the audio**

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Closed");
        //Here stop the audio
        e.getWindow().dispose();
    }
});
```

Comment: If i use JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, all the frames would close,and I only want to close the video player frame

Comment: That just says to use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE in place of EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Comment: @PrateekKalra answer updatred

Comment: Do you have any idea,how to stop the audio?